# Always show expanded Magit sections by default

Tags: magit

Sometimes the sections such as "Recent commits", will be closed by default. Can I set it so they are all always open by default?

But before I made the commit, recent commits was opened. After the commit, the unmerged section (with 1 commit in it) is closed. Is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

The `Recent commits` and `Unmerged into <upstream>` sections are actually two states of the same section. If there are any commits that haven't been merged into the upstream yet, then only those are shown, otherwise N recent commits are shown.

When you push or create a commit, that can cause the state to change. If that happens, then the section keeps its visibility state now (there may have been a bug related to that back when you asked this question).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly. I mean sometimes I will commit and the unmerged into upstream section will be folded: (Unmerged into ... (1)) or something. If i press tab I can view everything. Can I view everything by default?

Comment: So to recap. There is a section "Recent commits", you create a commit, as a result the "Recent commits" disappears and instead "Unmerged into ... (1)" appears. As I said, the visibility state of "Unmerged into ... (1)" depends on the visibility state of "Recent commits" before you created the commit.

Comment: By "will be folded" you mean "that action causes it to be displayed in folded state (it wasn't even visible before)", right?

Comment: All that being said I am also not quite happy with how all this is handled an plan to look into it again at a later time and maybe make some adjustments to the logic.

Comment: But before I made the commit, recent commits was opened. After the commit, the unmerged section (with 1 commit in it) is closed. Is this intended? I don't think it used to work this way, I think a relatively recent update may have changed it.

Comment: No that's not intended - provided I understand you correctly. I'll have a look soonish.